# Plotly express bar plot doesn't sort properly in streamlit (cache issues or bug in streamlit). Need Rerun from top 3lines each time to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, streamlit, python-polars

I have created a **dashboard** using `polars(python)`, `streamlit` which includes some **bar plots** that I need to keep it **sorted**.

**Webapp link**: https://vineet-eda-mmm.streamlit.app/

**Github Repo py file link**: https://github.com/johnsnow09/EDA_APP_MMM_LargeFile/blob/main/MMM_EDA-whole_data.py

I would like my data to stay sorted as in below image:
[image: Desired sorted chart]

But by default when I open the weblink it comes like below:
[image: Unsorted chart]

**Note:**

1. When I open the app it comes **unsorted** even in `incognito mode`.
2. It doesn't sort even on refreshing the page.
3. It doesn't sort even on `clearing cache` & then refreshing the page.
4. It **Sorts** and shows correct plot when I **"Rerun"** from the top right hand corner 3 lines.
5. Same is happening in other bar plots in this webapp as well.

Why would anyone visiting the link would know to click "Rerun" from the top3 lines. It looks like a **bug or cache problem to me**.

**Code** I have used to sort:

```
fig_pincode_gmv_facet = px.bar(df_pincode_gmv_facet(),
                                x='total_gmv',y='pincode',facet_col='Year',
                                orientation='h',
                                # hover_name='Party',
                                labels={
                                        "total_gmv": "Total GMV"
                                    },
                                category_orders={'Year':[2015,2016]},
                            
                            title=f'<b>Top 15 Pincodes by Total GMV in respective Years</b>'
                    
    ).update_yaxes(type='category', categoryorder='max ascending') #
    
    st.plotly_chart(fig_pincode_gmv_facet,use_container_width=True, config = config)
```

It doesn't seems like a code issue but would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**:

**1.**

If I comment `categoryorder` part of the code then graph changes to ascending sort of order

```
).update_yaxes(type='category') # , categoryorder='max ascending'
```

[image: graph changed on commenting categoryorder]

**2.**

I also have doubt on how **plotly express** `categoryorder='max ascending'` works. I ran code **locally** on `vscode` without `streamlit` and got **unsorted** graph, shown below:

[image: unsorted plot result in local vscode jupyter notebook]

Comment: I opened your site and saw the unordered graphs. I opened my inspect window and the browser redrew the graphs with the proper order. I think what's happening is that because streamlit uses websockets, the browser is getting the data to make the graph in a way plotly doesn't expect so it gets rendered out of order before the ordering gets to the browser. It only takes resizing the browser to force them in order. What happens if you take out the `categoryorder` and `category_orders` parameters? They should be redundant if the underlying df is sorted.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes it got `sorted` on resizing the browser window. `category_orders` is definitely effective as it is changing the facet years order and I commented them to see the difference. If I comment the whole line `update_yaxes(type='category', categoryorder='max ascending') ` then graph gets even weird with very thin bars/lines instead of usual bars. And when I comment `categoryorder='max ascending'` then it actually gives me reverse order like in ascending format. I will add the image in the `Update` at the end of the Post.